# ERRO LNK 1201 in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio

I have been trying to debug a program in Visual Studio on my Windows 10, but the following message appeared:

```
Error 1  fatal error LNK1201: error writing to program database 'C:\Users\Usu rio\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\Console3\Console3\debug\console3.pdb'; check for insufficient disk space, invalid path, or insufficient privilege
```

What I could do?

Comment: Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: I dont have a product like this or I cant found.

Comment: The solution is described in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648650).

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:

1. From `Build` menu, select `Clean Solution`. It will clean all debug symbols and program debug information.
2. Then select `Rebuild Solution` from the same menu. It will rebuild the solution, starting from a fresh cooy of PDB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did this steps and the error continues.